# i have a file all field are same then print line in bash? field is not fix

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have one file. plz leave $1. if all field  from $2..$x is same then print line.
 other wise not. No. of field is not fix.  Thanks in advance

```
input.txt
 1;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;
 2;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;TO;
 3;TO;DO;DO;TO;DO;
 4;DO;DO;DO;DO;TO;
 5;DO;DO;TO;DO;DO;
 6;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;
 7;DO;TO;DO;DO;TO;
 8;DO;TO;TO;DO;
 9;TO;TO;TO;TO;
Output:
 1;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;
 6;DO;DO;DO;DO;DO;
 9;TO;TO;TO;TO;
```

Comment: Please don't post "questions" that are just requests for code - instead, show us what you've tried and explain where you're stuck. See [ask] for more details on asking good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using awk

```
awk -F ';' '{same=1; for (i=3;i<NF;i++) { if ($i != $2) { same=0 } }; if (same == 1) {print $0}}' file
```

Here's how it works

```
'{
same=1;                         #assume all fields are the same
for (i=3;i<NF;i++) {            #for each field after the second
    if ($i != $2) { same=0 }    #test if the field is the same as 
                                #the second
}; 
if (same == 1) {print $0}       #if no difference were found, print the line
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed.

```
sed -n '/^[^;]*\(;[A-Za-z]\+\)\1\+$/p' file
```

- `[^;]*` matches the first field.
- `[A-Za-z]\+` Matches one or more letters.
- `\(;[A-Za-z]\+\)` Matches `;field`.
- `\1\+` repeats the chars inside first capturing group one or more times.

Comment: I hope that you were planning on making this a good answer by adding some explanation of what you've done.

Comment: ^^ Maybe after OP shows his/her attempts ;-)

Comment: Fails: echo "1;a;b;a" | sed -n '/^[^;]*\(;[A-Za-z]\+\)\+$/p' should not print this line but it does.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui OMG, i made a major mistake.. Check now..

Comment: Now it is ok, thanks.